# File path for Require / Include PHP

Tags: php, include

I know this might have been asked before but I can't figure out after reading them posts whats best for my situation. Sorry.

I'm having difficulties in declaring a file path for my include / require_once files.

My folder structure is like this.

```
 Root folder:
   index.php
   Folder(core)
       init.php
   Folder(user)
       registration.php
       login.php
       logout.php
       ....
   Folder(functions)
       functions.php
   Folder(inc)
       header.php
       footer.php
```

So the problem I'm having is that every time I try to include or require a file lets say from Folder(core) --> file init.php in Folder(user) -> File registration.php (registration.php would be where the include command be located) it throws me an error and page doesnt load. I get an error "Warning: require_once(/core/init.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory". Why is this happening? would be same if I try to include other files from different directories.

Please help, I know this might be a silly question but I can't figure out

Comment: Leave the beginning slash off

Comment: still doesnt work. I use Coda 2 and even if I preview in browser same thing. If I remove require_once command it works fine. Page loads

Comment: `/core` means that your operating system will start searching from the root node and not from where your files are located. That's what start slash does.

Comment: Post the actual code you're trying...

Comment: Possibly try `../core/init.php`

Comment: </head>
<body>
<?php
require_once('../core/init.php');
?>
<!-- Menu Horizontal -->
<div class="horizontal">

Comment: Coda 2 has this plugin insert file path. If i use it and select that folder with the file this what it gives me: Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/Slegaitis/Desktop/Web/core/init.php

Answer (score 0):

If your `index.php` is always loaded first and loads the other files that may also load other files, then everything is relative to the root directory:

`core/init.php`

Comment: Even if I do this: <?php
require_once('core/init.php');
?>  Still not working. I have no idea whats going on

Comment: May I say I include the php code inside my body just before all my html tags.

Comment: @user3306856  is used for if one file add before then this file will not add aging :)

Comment: Coda 2 has this plugin insert file path. If i use it and select that folder with the file this what it gives me: Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/Slegaitis/Desktop/Web/core/init.php